Python - custom type annotations for tree nodes and branches
I have a class representation of a ternary tree, where every node has three child nodes, which are generated via different "branches", which are actually generating functions for the child nodes. The class has methods which need to process the nodes and branches, and I would like to create the correct type annotations for these.
Each node is a tuple of (positive) integers (r, s), where r > s >= 1, and each "branch" is a callable, in this case, a lambda lambda x, y: # -> returns (f(x), f(y)), where f is the mathematical function associated with the branch - it produces integers. Branches take the unpacked args of a node and produce another node.
All nodes have the same form, and all three branches are of the same form but with  different generating functions.
Currently, I have the following typing for the nodes and branches, using the type parameter syntax introduced in 3.12:
from typing import Callable, Unpack
...
type TreeNode = tuple[int, int]
type TreeBranch = Callable[Unpack[TreeNode], TreeNode]

This seems correct, but I have a feeling I'm missing something. So this is my first question: given what I've described, are these type annotations correct?
Would the equivalent for 3.11 be?
TreeNode = TypeVar('TreeNode', bound=tuple[int, int])
Branch = TypeVar('TreeBranch', bound=Callable[Unpack[TreeNode], TreeNode])

Second question: the pairs of integers (r, s) in each node have the property that r > s >= 1. Is there a way of indicating this via type annotations?

This is incorrect:
type TreeBranch = Callable[Unpack[TreeNode], TreeNode]

The first type argument of Callable should be either a list or ...:
type TreeBranch = Callable[[Unpack[TreeNode]], TreeNode]

f: TreeBranch = lambda a, b: (b, a)  # fine

In 3.11 and older the types in question would be:
# 3.10+
from typing import TypeAlias
# Older
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias

TreeNode: TypeAlias = tuple[int, int]
TreeBranch: TypeAlias = Callable[[Unpack[TreeNode]], TreeNode]

As for the relationship between r and s, I believe there is currently no way to do so, other than Annotated:
from typing import Annotated

type TreeNode = Annotated[tuple[int, int], '(r, s); r > s >= 1']

